# Neo4J variable alias not recognized

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have three Person nodes with various relationships. Each node has a latitude and longitude.

[image]

First, I find the combinations of pairs of nodes:

```
MATCH (p1: Person)-[]->(p2: Person)
RETURN p1.name, p2.name
```

My output is correct:
[image]

Next, I attempt to find the distances between the pairs of nodes:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[]->(p2:Person)
WITH point({longitude: p1.longitude, latitude: p1.latitude}) AS p1Point,
point({longitude: p2.longitude, latitude: p2.latitude}) AS p2Point
RETURN (distance(p1Point, p2Point)) AS distance
```

My output is here:

[image]

Finally, I want to put it all together. I want to list the names of each node pair and the associated distance between them:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[]->(p2:Person)
WITH point({longitude: p1.longitude, latitude: p1.latitude}) AS p1Point,
point({longitude: p2.longitude, latitude: p2.latitude}) AS p2Point
RETURN p1.name, p2.name, (distance(p1Point, p2Point)) AS distance
```

I get an error that p1 is not defined.

[image]

What is the problem here? There is similar syntax described here:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/all-pairs-shortest-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WITH` clause unbinds all variables except for the ones it carries forward.

This should work:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-->(p2:Person)
WITH p1, p2,
  point({longitude: p1.longitude, latitude: p1.latitude}) AS p1Point,
  point({longitude: p2.longitude, latitude: p2.latitude}) AS p2Point
RETURN p1.name, p2.name, distance(p1Point, p2Point) AS distance
```

This should also work (since `WITH` is not really needed):

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-->(p2:Person)
RETURN p1.name, p2.name,
  distance(
    point({longitude: p1.longitude, latitude: p1.latitude}),
    point({longitude: p2.longitude, latitude: p2.latitude})) AS distance
```

[UPDATED]

*By the way, with an always-bidirectional relationship like `RELATED_TO`, you should just use a single [undirected relationship](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html) instead of two directed relationships pointing in opposite directions. Note, though, that the `CREATE` clause only supports creating *directed* relationships, so just pick any arbitrary direction -- it does not matter which. Later, when you do a search, just use an undirected search (like `MATCH (p1:Person)--(p2:Person) ...`). Also, you should look into whether you should use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead, since it does allow an undirected relationship pattern.*

Comment: Creating a bi-directional relationship would be great, but I get the error: "Only directed relationships are supported in CREATE"